# Scale fields in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How can I scale the fields in such a way that the mean is shifted to 0 and the standard deviation equals 1. Below is my dataframe.

```
var1 var2 var3
74   23    23
53   22    75
0    12    65
34   0      9
2    1      0
23   34     0
1    0      1
1    1      1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go with `sklearn` for this:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler = StandardScaler()

df[:] = scaler.fit_transform(df.values)

print(df)

    var1      var2      var3
0  1.915919  0.915927  0.043266
1  1.119200  0.835406  1.843137
2 -0.891566  0.030195  1.497008
3  0.398359 -0.936057 -0.441315
4 -0.815688 -0.855536 -0.752831
5 -0.018969  1.801658 -0.752831
6 -0.853627 -0.936057 -0.718218
7 -0.853627 -0.855536 -0.718218
```

Comment: i never understood why sklearn StandardScaler have std ~= 1.05 not ~1.0

Comment: I'm getting ones here `scaler.fit_transform(df.values).std(0)` @kenan

Comment: oh it might be because I copied your `df` and ran `df.describe()`, i guess the copy didn't get values after 6 decimals

Answer (score 2):

```
def standarize(x):
    return (x - x.mean()) / (x.std())
```

`df = df.apply(standarize)`

```
       var1      var2      var3
0  1.792178  0.856771  0.040472
1  1.046916  0.781451  1.724097
2 -0.833984  0.028245  1.400323
3  0.372631 -0.875601 -0.412812
4 -0.763006 -0.800281 -0.704209
5 -0.017744  1.685297 -0.704209
6 -0.798495 -0.875601 -0.671831
7 -0.798495 -0.800281 -0.671831
```

Verify results

```
df.describe()
               var1      var2      var3
count  8.000000e+00  8.000000  8.000000
**mean   0.000000  0.000000  0.000000**
**std    1.000000e+00  1.000000  1.000000**
min   -8.339838e-01 -0.875601 -0.704209
25%   -7.984951e-01 -0.819111 -0.679926
50%   -3.903754e-01 -0.386018 -0.542322
75%    5.412022e-01  0.800281  0.380435
max    1.792178e+00  1.685297  1.724097
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume the data follows a normal distribution. 
If `X = Norm(e, v^2)` then `Z = (X - e)/v == Norm(0, 1)`, with `e, v^2` are expected value and variance respectively.
Since your both `e` and `v^2` are unknown, you need to use `avg(X)` instead of `e` and `s^2` instead of `v^2` 
You should read `normal distribution` for more information